# Extract a String After a Substring in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, text

```
'(ep1270399)\nname=stet, johannes cornelis p/a ballast nedam infra b.v., p.o. box 1526 , city=3430 bm  nieuwegein , country=nl \n\nname=bos, wilhelmus johannes p/a ballast nedam infra b.v., p.o. box 1526 , city=3430 bm  nieuwegein , country=nl \n'
```

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to extract the name which is always after a certain keyword `\nname=`. Hence, I would like to get 'stet' and 'bos' and put it in an array.

Comment: can you post a sample dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string you provided is a string (Based on the quotations);

```
import re

string = '(ep1270399)\nname=stet, johannes cornelis p/a ballast nedam infra b.v., p.o. box 1526 , city=3430 bm nieuwegein , country=nl \n\nname=bos, wilhelmus johannes p/a ballast nedam infra b.v., p.o. box 1526 , city=3430 bm nieuwegein , country=nl \n'

split = re.split(' |=|,|\n', string)
result = [split[idx + 1] for idx, value in enumerate(split) if value == 'name']

result

['stet', 'bos']
```

This allows you to extract all values after `\nname=`. However if this data is stored differently, you will need to display so in your question so I can better tailor an answer for you!

You should be able to transfer the regex across to any format however.